# How can I load rows by name and role and order them based on their name, but preference the name? (SQL)

Tags: sql

What I mean is the following.

I have a database containing people. These people van a name and a role.
It looks like this:

```
-----------------------------
| (PK) id | name  | role    |
-----------------------------
| 1       | ben   | fireman |
| 2       | ron   | cook    |
| 3       | chris | coach   |
| 4       | remco | barber  |
-----------------------------
```

Ive created a searchbar where you can search for people in the database. When you press search, it looks for name and roles, for example:

When I type in 'co', the result I get is:

```
-----------------------------
| (PK) id | name  | role    |
-----------------------------
| 3       | chris | coach   |
| 4       | remco | barber  |
| 2       | ron   | cook    |
-----------------------------
```

This is because its looking for matches in the name and role column.
The query I use is:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '$search' OR role LIKE '$search' ORDER BY name";
```

The only issue with this is that it just order by name.
I want it to first order every result from the name column by name and then order every remaining result from the role column by name, so it ends up looking like this:

```
-----------------------------
| (PK) id | name  | role    |
-----------------------------
| 4       | remco | barber  |  <-  'co' found in name column, ordered by name
| 3       | chris | coach   |  <-  'co' found in role column, ordered by name
| 2       | ron   | cook    |  <-  'co' found in role column, ordered by name
-----------------------------
```

How can I do this?

Edit: $search is the output from the searchbar

Answer (score 3):

Use a `case` *expression* to put the 'co' names first:

```
order by case when name LIKE '$search' then 0 else 1 end, name, role
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!